# Why I can't find the loader element from parent element?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the full code: https://codepen.io/dotku/pen/gyVZqj?editors=1011

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <span class="loader">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

```js
  if (!containerElement) {
    console.log('Carousel element is required.')
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(
      'Carousel element is found',
      document.querySelector(`#${containerID}`)
    );
  }
```

I have a checking statement, but the `document.querySelector` won't return the loader. Why?

Comment: Well that is not pure javascript code, we can not know what is being rendered as the selector. Please edit the example to be [mcve].

Comment: @Esko Thanks, I just don't know what should be clear; but you are right, I just double check the code there is just one online remove the loader already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug!
There is one line which removed the loader tag, that's why.

```
containerElement.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0].remove()
```